# Revert/rollback record states on error

Tags: visualforce, controller, exception, dmlexception, rollback

Consider the following block of code that is called on save of a basic data entry page:

```
public PageReference save()
{
    // accounts is binded to VF page
    for (Account a : accounts)
    {
        // assume Amount__c is never null
        a.Amount__c += 10;
    }

    try { update accounts; }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
    }

    return getPageReference();
}
```

Assume user makes a mistake and clicks save. The exception is thrown and caught, but the value of the Amount__c field has now gone up. If the user corrects their mistake and clicks save the Amount__c will increment by another 10.

What is the correct way of "remembering" the original field values? I am hoping caching the initial state of records is not an answer!

Answer (score 4):

The other two answers basically say the same thing, and they're on the right track, but you really have three choices here: (a) "cache" the old values, (b) perform your operations in a separate function, (c) reload the values back from the database, or otherwise revert them.

While the others recommend essentially cloning, this can cause a loss of error messages. Instead, backup your values, try the DML, then copy values back. That might look like this:

```
Account[] backup = accounts.deepClone(true, true, true);
for(Account a: accounts) {
    a.Amount__c += 10;
}
try {
    update accounts;
} catch(Exeption e) {
    Database.rollback(sp);
    for(Integer index = 0, size = backup.size(); index < size; index++) {
        accounts[index].Amount__c = backup[index].Amount__c;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can perform your updates elsewhere. That might look like this:

```
Boolean firstAttempt = true;
public PageReference doAction() {
    if(firstAttempt) {
        for(Account a: accounts) {
            a.Amount__c += 10;
        }
    }
    firstAttempt = false;
    // Now, do your DML, as above
}
```

Finally, if the records were already saved, the third option would simply be to read the values back:

```
public PageReference doAction() {
try {
    for(Account a: accounts) {
        a.Amount__c += 10;
    }
    update accounts;
} catch(Exception e) {
    Map<Id, Account> orig = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Amount__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accounts]);
    for(Account a: accounts) {
        a.Amount__c = orig.get(a.Id).Amount__c;
    }
}
```

Any of these three methods would avoid losing the original error messages, allowing the users to correct mistakes without double-work.

Note that you could also choose to simply remember how much each value was incremented by, and *decrement* by the same amount if an exception is caught.

Personally, I'd avoid all of these methods, and instead have the *trigger* perform the changes to the record. If you do this, the original values will remain untouched in the page, and will only persist if the trigger runs without errors/exceptions. The only downside to this approach would be that you'd have to reload the values from the database on a *successful* save if you need to show the new values later.

Answer (score 2):

With your specific example you could use this technique of using temporary objects in the save method:

```
Account[] updates = new Account[] {};
for (Account a : accounts)
{
    updates.add(new Account(Id = a.Id, Amount__c = a.Amount__c + 10));
}
try { update updates; }
```

In general you can clone the objects in the save and update the clones. But yes this all amounts to "remembering" the original field values.

Comment: The downside of this method is that you "lose" your error messages (e.g. the clones can't tell the originals field level errors, thus can't be rendered correctly by Visualforce).

Comment: Definitely a good alternative but sfdcbox's point is valid and well taken.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with few different ways..

one option i can think of is to create a new collection and change the values like below

```
public PageReference save()
{
    List<Account> accsToUpdate = new List<Account>()
    // accounts is binded to VF page
    for (Account a : accounts)
    {
        Account acc = new Account(Id = a.Id, Amount__c = a.Amount__c + 10);
        accsToUpdate.add(acc);
    }

    try { update accsToUpdate; }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
    }

    return getPageReference();
}
```

the other option might be to have a method to revert back the values from the original collection and call that method from the catch block ..

and definitely there will be few other options